# Bind a label in array of labels

Tags: c#

I have an array of labels. I use these command lines to bind the Label's text to a column in my table, but it is not binding properly.

Here is the applicable code:

```
Label[] LL = new Label[26];
for (int i = 0; i < LL.Length; i++)
{
    LL[i] = new Label();
    LL[i].Text = null;
}

LL[0].DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text",
                       this.table_010_UserInfoBindingSource, "Column07", true));
```

Comment: "Not binding properly" is really vague, can you tell us what you mean?

Answer (score 5):

You are only binding the first label in your array. Move the `LL[0].Databindings.Add...` line up into the for loop. Also, change the `LL[0]` to `LL[i]` or you will bind the same label over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

The DataBinding statement needs to be inside the `for` loop